# Do I need to have watched Better Call Saul before El Camino?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul, el-camino-a-breaking-bad-movie

Is there any plot structure in ***Better Call Saul*** that is vital -- or even just highly recommended -- to comprehension of *El Camino*, or is just a good working knowledge of Breaking Bad good enough?

I'm trying to avoid spoilers for either *Saul* or *Camino*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. I finished Breaking Bad same year it ended and just recently watched El Camino. I was able to follow along no problem.

As long as you watched the last 2 seasons of Breaking Bad, you'll be fine. There are a few little things that come up in El Camino that you won't understand if you haven't finished the Breaking Bad series.

There is no reference to Saul in the movie. The movie gives closure to Breaking Bad by explaining what happened to Jesse after the final episode.

Comment: There is one BCS Easter egg in El Camino. The guy who drives the strippers to the welder’s shop is the third guy who showed up for the body guard job. Mike disarms and incapacitated the loud mouth and offers him one of the guns he took and the guy runs away, so Mike takes the job alone. The guy who runs away is the strippers’ bodyguard.

Comment: 'The guy' is man mountain. I think he was also one of the two that help Saul scare the punks who rob him while trying to sell his phones